# Gremlin query cosmosDB to find a connection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have a graph modeled this way. `A` --`calls('for', 'Item1')`--> `B` --`calls('for', 'Item1')`--> `C` --`calls('for', 'Item1')`--> `D`.
`A` calls `B` for `Item1`(property of the edge). `B` `calls` `C` and `C` `calls` `D`. There can be other chains as well in the graph that would have some vertex call `D` for `Item1`. How can i determine all such chains? All the ways in which `D` can be called for `Item1`.

Apologies if the question is too basic. My knowledge on graph is very minimal and I am using cosmosDB to model this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I would start at "D" and follow "Item1" paths from there using `repeat()`. Assuming "D" is the actual `T.id` (element identifier):

```
g.V("D").repeat(inE('calls').has('for','Item1').outV()).emit().path()
```

The above is the beginnings of such a query. You might need a terminating condition to that `repeat()` loop and methods to avoid cycles (i.e. `simplePath()`) if your graph contains such things so that you avoid infinite traversals along such paths.

Comment: this is causing a lot of duplicates though. how can i optimize this query to dedup the output.

Comment: Exact path duplicates could be removed by adding `dedup()` to the end of the traversal.